# How to add a unique string before and after a character in a string

Tags: c#

I have a string "AAAA", and I need to add certain lines before each character in this string.
For example, given

```
string original = "AAAA". 
string firstStringBeforeChar = "B"
string firststringAfterChar = "C"
```

and after the conversion, I want to get a string:

```
string converted = "BACAAA"
```

For each index, the original string will have its own stringBeforeChar and stringAfterChar. The final output should be like this:

```
string converted = "BACBACBACBAC"
```

Where B and C are unique strings for each character in the string original.  How do I do this?

Comment: There are multiple approaches to this problem. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Tomsen There is an option to write a method string Replacement(string original, string first, string second) => first + original + second and probably go through each element and replace it. And what methods can you suggest?

Comment: `string converted = string.Concat(original.Select(c => firstStringBeforeChar + c + firststringAfterChar));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a loop to iterate through each character in the original string, and use the StringBuilder class to append the appropriate strings before and after each character

Example:

```cs
using System.Text;

string original = "AAAA";
string[] stringBeforeChar = {"B", "D", "E", "F"};
string[] stringAfterChar = {"C", "G", "H", "I"};

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < original.Length; i++)
{
    sb.Append(stringBeforeChar[i]);
    sb.Append(original[i]);
    sb.Append(stringAfterChar[i]);
}

string converted = sb.ToString();
Console.WriteLine(converted);
Console.WriteLine(converted);
```

Output:

```
BACDAGEAHFAI
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in a single line of code.

```cs
string converted = original.Replace(original[0].ToString(), $"{firstStringBeforeChar}{original[0]}{firststringAfterChar}");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this, if that's what you are asking:

```
    string original = "AAAA";
    string firstStringBeforeCharacter = "B";
    string firstStringAfterCharacter = "C";
    var result = new StringBuilder();
    foreach(var c in original)
    {
        result.Append($"{firstStringBeforeCharacter}{c}{firstStringAfterCharacter}");
    }

    Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add before and after *character* you can try Linq: for each character `c` we decide what to put into `result` and then `Concat` all our decisions into the finla string.

If you want to add before *certain* char, here it is `'A'`:

```
using System.Linq;

...

var result = string.Concat(original 
  .Select(c => c == 'A'
             ? $"{firstStringBeforeChar}{c}{firststringAfterChar}"
             : $"{c}"));
```

If you want to add before / after *any* char, drop the condition:

```
using System.Linq;

...

var result = string.Concat(original 
  .Select(c => $"{firstStringBeforeChar}{c}{firststringAfterChar}"));
```